# WordPress shortcode to display message based on value used by plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm hoping someone can clue me in on how I can extract a plugin value and display it on my page using a short code. Specifically, when a user reaches the max allowable limit, I would like a notification message to appear on the page (in addition to its placement in a popup) Many tests and I have not been able to get this to work. MANY thanks in advance.

```php
public function add_error_limit_message() {

            if ( ! $this->limit_reached ) {
                return;
            }

            $message = apply_filters( 'woocompare_limit_reached_message', __( 'You have reached the maximum number of products for compare table.', 'woocommerce-compare' ) );
            echo '<div class="woocompare-error"><p>' . wp_kses_post( $message ) . '</p></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'limit-reached-message', 'add_error_limit_message' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shortcode function should `return` the text string you want to insert in place of the shortcode, not `echo` it.

To track down "critical errors" (php errors) turn on [WP_DEBUG](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY in your wp-config.php file. And try installing and activating the Query Monitor plugin.  These will tell you enough about your php errors to track them down and fix them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately, my code generates a critical error. Not sure if I can leverage the plugin values, if I need make specific API calls first, or if I can duplicate the entire script and remove everything except those related to the cookie value and error message?